# Alternative serialization for DataMapper objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, serialization, datamapper

I'm working on on a caching layer in my Rails app and I'm having trouble caching original DataMapper objects. They seem to have a lot of stuff attached that make marshaling fail (I get an error about Marshal being unable to serialize a Proc object).

So I am considering writing my own pre-serialization and post-deserialization methods for caching. Specifically I will turn the DataMapper object into a list of tuples with this:

```
o = Foo.get(1234)
as_list = o.model.properties.map { |p| [p.name, o.send(p.name)] }
```

And then cache that list.

My question is: How do I reconstruct the DataMapper object in a way that allows me to use it as it if were constructed by a normal DataMapper query?

My naive approach of `Foo.new(foo=bar, goo=baz)` doesn't seem to connect it up with all of the foreign keys and stuff.

Comment: For what it's worth, since 1.0'ish I've not had any of the structural problems that used to plague DM with Marshall#dump. But, I've found complex objects can dump to > 1-2MB (even after LZO compression) and so caching is still a non-starter. I'm really looking forward to any suggestions you get here; please answer it yourself if you come up with anything remotely workable later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some "fun" code-spelunking I seem to have found something that works:

```
mc.set(key, HashWithIndifferentAccess[o.attributes])

as_hash = mc.get(key)
from_cache = Foo.load([as_hash], Foo.all.query).first
```

The `load` method on the model seems to be what get uses and the `query` seems to be required in order to get the repository names and a few other things.